# Prove that $t\mapsto \frac{d}{dt}\left[\rho(t)\right]^{-1}=-\rho(t)^{-1}\rho'(t)\rho(t)^{-1}$

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, multivariable-calculus, convergence-divergence, uniform-convergence

Let $\rho:(a,b)\to \operatorname{ISO}\left(\Bbb{R}^n\right)$ be differentiable. I want to prove that 
\begin{align}\frac{d}{dt}\left[\rho(t)\right]^{-1}=-\rho(t)^{-1}\rho'(t)\rho(t)^{-1}\end{align} 
$\operatorname{ISO}\left(\Bbb{R}^n\right)$ is a space of continuous linear maps from $\Bbb{R}^n$ to $\Bbb{R}^n$. I have proven before that

\begin{align}f:\operatorname{ISO}\left(\Bbb{R}^n\right)\to \operatorname{ISO}\left(\Bbb{R}^n\right)\end{align} 
\begin{align}u\mapsto u^{-1}\end{align}is differentiable and
\begin{align}f'(u)(h)=-u^{-1}h u^{-1}\end{align} 
 Along the line, I used Neumann's Lemma but I got stuck when proving this.

**Here is my work:**

I tried by using definition:

Let $h\in(a,b),$ then
\begin{align}\rho(t+h)-\rho(t)&=\rho(t+h)^{-1}-\rho(t)^{-1}\\&=\left[\rho(t+h)-\rho(t)+\rho(t)\right]^{-1}-\rho(t)^{-1}\\&=\left[\left[\left(\rho(t+h)-\rho(t)\right)\left(\rho(t)\right)+I\right]^{-1}-I\right]\rho(t)^{-1}\end{align}
I'm thinking of applying Neumann's Lemma but I can't move on. I want someone to help see my fault. Otherwise, alternative methods will be highly regarded. Thanks!

Comment: What is $\text{ISO}(\Bbb R^n)$?

Comment: @edm: Some moments, please!

Comment: Linear maps on $\Bbb R^n$ are automatically continuous, so that saying the linear map is "continuous" is redundant. Meanwhile, not all linear maps have inverses, so you may want to restrict the domain and codomain of the map to general linear group.

The symbol $\rho$ appeared twice with different meanings. You may want to correct that.

Comment: @edm: I edited it!

Comment: Your notation is a bit confusing for me but you might perhaps want this: $0=\frac{d}{dt}I = \frac{d}{dt}(AA^{-1}) = \frac{d}{dt}(A)A^{-1} + A\frac{d}{dt}A^{-1}$ where $A$ is a shortcut for $\rho(t)$. But again, I might have misunderstood what exactly you want to prove.

Answer (score 1):

Idea:
$$\forall t\in(a,b): \left[\rho(t)\right]^{-1}\rho(t) = I\ \hbox{(constant)},$$
so
$$
0 = \frac{d}{dt}(\left[\rho(t)\right]^{-1}\rho(t)) =
(\frac{d}{dt}\left[\rho(t)\right]^{-1})\rho(t) + \rho(t)^{-1}\frac{d}{dt}\rho(t).
$$